# how to refresh listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to enable and disable certain LinearLayout. This is inside ListView Item. I called notifyDataSetChanged. But getView is not called and layout is not getting visible. How can I refresh view inside OnClick in GetView?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qna_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    final ImageView openBtn= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.qna_list_item_open_btn);
    final LinearLayout replyView = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qna_list_item_reply);
    openBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            replyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            openBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_btn_up);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call notifyDatasetChanged like: AdapterClass.this.notifyDatasetChanged()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your adapter data/model **not** your item views, then you can call `notifyDataSetChanged();` to refresh the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Set these Porperties to your ListView

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Then in onClick directly you can Set Visibilty ,no need to Refresh

```
 openBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                replyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                openBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_btn_up);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this:

```
myListView.invalidateViews();
```

OR

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` object once you've modified the data in that adapter.